# redshift - how to insert into table generated time series

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to generate time series in Redshift and insert into table, but no luck. What I have tried so far:

```
insert into date(dateid,date)
SELECT
    to_char(datum, 'YYYYMMDD')::int AS dateid,
    datum::date AS date
FROM (
    select '1970-01-01'::date + generate_series(0, 20000) as datum
     ) tbl;
```

Getting the following error

```
SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

Any ideas or workaround ?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `generate_series()` can be run on the Leader node, but **not on a compute node**.

Therefore, it is possible to run a statement like this:

```
SELECT '1970-01-01'::date + generate_series(0, 20000)
```

However, it is not possible to use that statement in a `FROM` because that would involve the compute nodes.

**Solution:** Create a table of information externally and load the results into a `date` table, or use `generate_series()` directly to generate the desired values, save the results and import them into a `date` table.

Comment: I basically wrote a Talend job which selects using generate_series() and dynamically insets into the table

Answer (score 2):

**The generate_series function does not work on Redshift**

it does however generate_confusion! This is because it looks like its working fine until you try to write to a table.

Technically, the reason for this is that it works ONLY on the leader node. and the leader node itself does not have access to the tables directly.

If you try

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE::TIMESTAMP - (i * interval '1 day') as date_datetime
FROM generate_series(1,31) i
ORDER BY 1;
```

That produces a nice table output, because it has run on the leader node.

HOWEVER
if you run

```
create table test as
SELECT CURRENT_DATE::TIMESTAMP - (i * interval '1 day') as date_datetime
FROM generate_series(1,31) i
ORDER BY 1;
```

This fails with

> [2019-03-11 07:38:00] [0A000] ERROR: Specified types or functions (one
>   per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables. [2019-03-11
>   07:38:00] [00000] Function "generate_series(integer,integer)" not
>   supported.

This is because we are now trying to create a table, so the sql has to be run on the worker nodes (not the leader node) and so it fails.

Comment: . . If you put the `generate_series()` in a CTE, does that work?

Comment: No, it doesn't - in redshift a cte is just like a subquery (unlike postgres). (i did test it just in case - same error)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may generate the integer sequence using a query like the following:

```
WITH
digits AS (
    SELECT 0 AS v
    UNION SELECT 1
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5
    UNION SELECT 6
    UNION SELECT 7
    UNION SELECT 8
    UNION SELECT 9
), 
seq AS (
    SELECT 10000*tens_of_thousands.v + 1000*thousands.v + 100*hundreds.v + 10*tens.v + units.v AS seq
    FROM digits as units
    CROSS JOIN digits AS tens
    CROSS JOIN digits AS hundreds
    CROSS JOIN digits AS thousands
    CROSS JOIN digits AS tens_of_thousands
    ORDER BY seq
)
SELECT * FROM seq;
```