# Trying to create a date sequence yyyymmdd

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a date range sequence in the following format yyyymmdd

```
insert into dim_SH (date_key)
SELECT to_char(('2012-01-01'::date + x)::date,'yyyymmdd') 
FROM generate_series(1, 365*15, 1) x;
```

> Amazon Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
>   1 statement failed.

Comment: Please search for creating calendar table in redshift. You CANNOT use generate_series.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redshift - how to insert into table generated time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092657/redshift-how-to-insert-into-table-generated-time-series)

Answer (score 0):

It's true that `GENERATE_SERIES` is *supposedly* not supported by Redshift (here's [Redshift documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html) saying that it is not supported) and therefore whenever you need to generate rows, you have to create them on the fly (like below):

```
WITH ten as (
  select 1 union all
  select 1 union all
  select 1 union all
  select 1 union all
  select 1 union all
  select 1 union all
  select 1 union all
  select 1 union all
  select 1 union all
  select 1
), ten_k as (
  select row_number() over () as x
  from ten a cross join
     ten b cross join
     ten c cross join
     ten d
  )
SELECT to_char(('2012-01-01'::date + x)::date,'yyyymmdd')
FROM ten_k limit 365*15;
```

Alternatively you can select rows from somewhere:

```
SELECT x FROM (SELECT row_number() over () as x FROM arbitrary_table limit 10000) as ten_k
```

---

## Is `GENERATE_SERIES` really not supported?

I was **shocked** to see that the query you posted:

```
SELECT to_char(('2012-01-01'::date + x)::date,'yyyymmdd')
FROM generate_series(1, 365*15, 1) x;
```

actually worked when ran against our Redshift (in version 1.0.7078). [Release notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/rs-mgmt-cluster-version-notes.html#rs-mgmt-cluster-version-notes-107078) do not mention any *new* functionality in that area [:puzzled:].

**EDIT:**
Apparently [as of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55094110/1680826), `generate_series` works *on leader node only*, but fails whenever your query need to reach the compute nodes.

Hence, not fully supporting this function deems it *unsupported*.